# Finding All Pixels Within Certain Range in Polar Coordinates

Tags: image-processing, graphics, geometry, computational-geometry, polar-coordinates

I want to find all pixels in an image (in Cartesian coordinates) which lie within certain polar range, r_min r_max theta_min and theta_max. So in other words I have some annular section defined with the parameters mentioned above and I want to find integer x,y coordinates of the pixels which lie within it. The brute force solution comes to mid offcourse (going through all the pixels of the image and checking if it is within it) but I am wondering if there is some more efficient solution to it.

Thanks

Comment: What language? Depending on what language you're considering, the brute force approach can actually be quite efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the brute force solution, you can first determine the tight bounding box of the area, by computing the four vertexes and including the four cardinal extreme points as needed. Then for every pixel, you will have to evaluate two circles (quadratic expressions) and two straight lines (linear expressions). By doing the computation incrementally (X => X+1) the number of operations drops to about nothing.

Inside a circle

```
f(X,Y) = X²+Y²-2XXc-2YYc+Xc²+Yc²-R² <= 0
```

Incrementally,

```
f(X+1,Y) = f(X,Y)+2X+1-2Xc <= 0
```

If you really want to avoid that overhead, you will resort to scanline conversion techniques. First think of filling a slanted rectangle. Drawing two horizontal lines by the intermediate vertices, you decompose the rectangle in two triangles and a parallelogram. Then for any scanline that crosses one of these shapes, you know beforehand what pair of sides you will intersect. From there, you know what portion of the scanline you need to fill.

You can generalize to any shape, in particular your circle segment. Be prepared to a relatively subtle case analysis, but finding the intersections themselves isn't so hard. It may help to split the domain with a vertical through the center so that any horizontal always meets the outline twice, never four times.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

We'll assume the center of the section is at 0,0 for simplicity. If not, it's easy to change by offsetting all the coordinates.

For each possible y coordinate from `r_max` to `-r_max`, find the x coordinates of the circle of both radii: `-sqrt(r*r-y*y)` and `sqrt(r*r-y*y)`. For every point that is inside the `r_max` circle and outside the `r_min` circle, it *might* be part of the section and will need further testing.

Now do the same x coordinate calculations, but this time with the line segments described by the angles. You'll need some conditional logic to determine which side of the line is inside and which is outside, and whether it affects the upper or lower part of the section.